# Is there any possibility to use TLS12 SslStream in Xamarin for Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, tls1.2, sslstream

I know that Mono doesn't support TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 in current version of Xamarin so maybe there is possibility to implement TLS12 on my way?

This part of code doesn't work for Xamarin.Android:

```
_clientSocket = new TcpClient();
await _clientSocket.ConnectAsync(host, port);
_stream = new SslStream(_clientSocket.GetStream(), false);
_stream.AuthenticateAsClient(host, null, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
```

Comment: Xamarin brought TLS 1.2 support in Cycle 7 Alpha 1 back in March, https://releases.xamarin.com/alpha-preview-1-cycle-7/ so it should already land on the version (Cycle 8 Update 1) you use if you check carefully.

Comment: You use AuthenticateAsClient. Do you have certs installed on the phone? Are those certs self-signed?

Comment: @LexLi thanks I need to check, I didn't know

Comment: @SushiHangover authentication via TLS12 (server always get TLS1 from client even if I set TLS12 like above in example)

Comment: @YuriS I don't need it to install cert on the phone because is trusted - not self-signed. When I set to TLS12 (example above) - on the server I get always TLS1 from client because Mono support TLS1 for Mono SslStream.

Comment: As @SushiHangover said what doesn't work? What exception you are getting?

Comment: @YuriS or @SushiHangover

**Client exception:**

The authentication or decryption has failed.

**Server output** (see client hello, server thinks that client is TLS1 and it is truth because setting TLS12 on client doesn't work for Xamarin.Android):

`878893, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 80
ClientHello, TLSv1
878893, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
878893, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol TLSv1 not enabled or not supported`

Comment: And your server supports ONLY TLS12? Can you use Http or this is not an option? Can you share URI you are connecting for us to try some options? Are you writing or reading first from socket?

Comment: Yes, only support TLS12 because I don't want to use SSL in all versions and TLS1-1.1 be cause of POODLE attack.

Comment: Can you answer the rest of my question please

Comment: I can't use HTTP because this is a socket connection via PROTOBUF (real-time application) but TLS12 for HTTP rest api works very well using ModernHttpClient for all platforms in Xamarin (but that's another story).

There is no reading from the server, the server immediately breaks the connection just for safe.

Comment: If you don't read why you connect at all :-) Can you share your URI? If any SSL client can do it I assume it is not a secret URI?

Comment: @SushiHangover Android 6.0 - API 23

Comment: It seems your cert is self-signed. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the SSL/TLS Implementation to `Native TLS 1.2+`
 so `BoringSsl` is used vs. Mono's managed TLS. If the managed implementation is used, your client will only negotiate 1.1.

[image]

```
var _clientSocket = new TcpClient();
using (var _stream = new SslStream(_clientSocket.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidation)))
{
    await _stream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(host, null, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
    // do something with your stream

    // FYI: Bug/Issue with Xamarin.Android, the following always return `None`
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"CipherAlgorithm: {_stream.CipherAlgorithm.ToString()}");
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"KeyExchangeAlgorithm: {_stream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm.ToString()}");
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"HashAlgorithm: {_stream.HashAlgorithm.ToString()}");

    // The following are not implemented in Xamarin Mobile, tagged as "Need to Implement"
    // Mobile CipherStrength = NotImplementedException
    // Mobile KeyExchangeStrength = NotImplementedException
    // Mobile HashStrength = NotImplementedException

}
```

- Handling `RemoteCertificateChainErrors`

In order to handle the `RemoteCertificateChainErrors` on the Self-Signed cert, you can provide a custom `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`, while you can just provide a `true`, you should actually check that the correct server/cert is provided but adding it to the TrustManager would be the preferred/secure way...

```
static bool CertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors certificateErrors)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CertificateValidation");
    Console.WriteLine(certificate.ToString(true));
    Console.WriteLine("Chain");
    Console.WriteLine(chain);
    Console.WriteLine("\tError(s)");
    Console.WriteLine(certificateErrors);
    Console.WriteLine();
    return true;
}
```

#### Update:

Manual setting via `.csproj` (or `xbuild/msbuild`), within the `PropertyGroup` for release/debug you can add:

```
<AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
<AndroidTlsProvider>btls</AndroidTlsProvider>
```

Comment: thank you for help, it works :) I was thinking about something similar a few days ago but I didn't know that can be like yours solution for this problem. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: @user1701235 Glad to here it... Happy SSLSteam'ing ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover Are these setting in Xamarin Studio? Any similar settings in VS?

Comment: @YuriS https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/#Xamarin.Android

Comment: @YuriS Native TLS 1.2+ in Visual Studio showed me after upgrade to newest Xamarin Alpha

Comment: With Visual Studio 2017 we get stable version of Xamarin with TLS 1.2 support for sockets and rest API.